# Space Salvage Company Book

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a book I read in the early 80's.  The opening chapter is a spaceship (owned by a salvage company?) has to rescue a passenger vessel that is trapped in the atmosphere of a Jupiter like gas giant.  The passengers are saved by the salvage ship passing an umbilical to the passenger ship.  This introduces the daughter of a missing scientist who has created some universe changing something.  She hires the salvage ship to find her missing father.  The missing father may have been found in a hollow asteroid.

Edit: book may have been published before the 80's, I used to read anything in the library that had a rocket ship on the cover.  I remember the opening being a commercial operation that had to rescue a passenger vessel and concern by the captain about the cost of the operation and whether he would get paid for it.

Comment: I don't think Forgotten Star is the right book.  The first part of the book was about a commercial operation rescuing a trapped ship.  I seem to recall concern by the captain of the ship about the cost of the rescue and would they get paid.

Comment: Several points kept tantalisingly reminding me of something. It turned out to be Alastair Reynolds' *Redemption Ark* (2002) - which of course is not the answer. I'll get me coat.

Comment: Was the father's world-changing gizmo an 'anoptikon'?  I dimly recall that feature of a similar story.   Cannot recall the name.